# Can you hyperlink a google sheets checkbox?

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to create a situation in a google sheet in which a true/false checkbox, if checked (true) is also a mailto hyperlink.

In other words, if you check the box, you also get a gmail popup with the to address filled in.

Anyone know what the formula for this would be?

I tried to add a hyperlink to the checkbox and got error message "this cells contents violate its validation rule."

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine your expected result. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Thank you for your reply… I'm now having to change my approach from the true/false to a range of dates. 

Will submit a separate question about how to compose an email based on a range of dates in a spreadsheet.